# How to access gitlab issue iteration changes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm trying to get the information out of gitlab, when I changed the iteration of a an issue. Meaning: "when I moved a ticket from Sprint 5 to Sprint 6".
I tried over the API, graphql, database... Every solution/help would be really appreciated. Even just telling me in which table it is stored would be helpful.
I know there is a field of iteration in the issue table and also in the queries, but I need the historical information. Meaning I want to know if a ticket moved from Sprint 1 to 2 to 3 etc...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution:

```
GET /projects/:id/issues/:issue_iid/resource_iteration_events
```

[see also](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/resource_iteration_events.html)